# Want to populate all existing contact data on lead creation if email entered matches existing contact email

Tags: trigger

For this a trigger should be implemented before insert which checks email address on existing contact and auto fills all contact fields on Lead.
Can anyone help with the code:

i want to populate the Contact's  Salutation,First name,Lastname,Title,Phone,MobilePhone

- Account's  name  as Company name,Account's country as Lead country,Account's address                                               as lead Address.

Please have a look at below & let me know where i am making error:-

```
trigger LeadContact on Lead (before insert) {

List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact> ();

Set<String> existed_ContactEmailSet = new Set<String>();

for(Contact con : [Select id,email,Lastname,account.name,phone,MobilePhone,account.BillingAddress FROM Contact  where email !=null]){

existed_ContactEmailSet.add(con.email);
conList.add(con);
}

for(lead ld : Trigger.new){

   if(ld.email !=null && !existed_ContactEmailSet.isEmpty() && existed_ContactEmailSet.contains(ld.email) && !conlist.isEmpty()){

      ld.Lastname = conList.Lastname;
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe the _specific problem_ you are encountering with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Besides for some questions like "why do you actually want to create a new lead, if there is an already existing contact?", etc., here's a potential solution:

```
trigger LeadContact on Lead (before insert) {
    // As you can get a list of up to 200 leads when the trigger runs
    // you should put the email addresses in a set
    Set<String> leadMailAddresses = new Set<String>();
    for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) {
        leadMailAddresses.add(lead.Email);
    }
    // get contacts, based on email
    // include all the fields you need
    List<Contact> contacts = [
            SELECT
                    Id,
                    Email,
                    FirstName,
                    LastName
            FROM
                    Contact
            WHERE Email IN :leadMailAddresses
    ];
    //For faster execution put the query results in a Map<EmailAddress, Contact>
    Map<String, Contact> emailContactMap = new Map<String, Contact>();
    for(Contact contact : contact){
        emailContactMap.put(contact.Email, contact);
    }
    // Now fill your lead details
    for(Lead lead : Trigger.new){
        Contact foundContact = emailContactMap.get(lead.Email);
        if(foundContact == null){
            continue;
        }
        lead.FirstName = foundContact.FirstName;
        // ... continue with the other fields
    }
}
```

In any case: take care of [Execution Governors and Limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)